# Is there a name for trivial WP PHP files like functions.php, archive php entry.php, page.php and so forth?

Tags: php, theme-development, wp-filesystem

Is there a name for trivial WP PHP files like functions.php, archive php entry.php, page.php and so forth?

Is there a "category" (in the general sense of the term) they all fall into?

I want to know how to name them so I could read about them so I could figure our which of them is actually mandatory in the latest versions of WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't have a special name, they are just theme / template files. If you want to read more about them in general, see [template files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/) in the codex. The [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) is also something you'll need to know about, it explains what file gets chosen when.

Comment: Indeed I know the concept of template hierarchy, I will read more on it after reading in the first link. Thank you for the explanation and links. Thumbed up.